# How to change the template for all the pages of product review?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

How to change `1 column` on `3column` for all the pages of product review?

[image]

Comment: As per as,you screen shot,***this product  details page not product review page***.

And it handler is `catalog_product_view`.

So,you need change it template *`catalog.xml`(app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout)*

Comment: That's right! Thank you! I changed `catalog.xml` `<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per as,your screen shot,*this is product details page not product review page*. And it handler  should be `catalog_product_view`.

So,you need change it template  at  handler ***`catalog_product_view`***  in catalog.xml(`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout`)

```
   <catalog_product_view translate="label">
 .......
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please go to catalog.xml located at `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/review.xml`

Looking for

```
<review_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product Review View</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="review/view" name="review_view"/>
    </reference>
</review_product_view>
```

Change template from `page/2columns-right` to `page/1column`

It will look like this

```
  <review_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product Review View</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="review/view" name="review_view"/>
    </reference>
</review_product_view>
```

Hope this help!!!

Comment: Thank you! But it is a different location.

Comment: You mentioned product review page so must be that file. I added a note for product view page but I had to edit :). Anyway, you got solution already.

Comment: I apologize for my mistake.